# Angular template no longer displaying select list options

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In our codebase some class property names were updated and those classes turned out to be used by some Angular js files.

I have debugged it to the point that I know bTargets has data in it, but can someone explain what the ng-options attribute is actually doing under the hood?

```
<select class="BranchRuleTargetSelect" ng-model="branchTargetID" ng-options="t.ID as t.Text for t in bTargets" />
```

This select does not output any options, but there is data in bTargets object.

There is a property called ID and Text inside bTargets object so I am wondering if that is breaking the expression, as it looks like it is using an alias of some sort.

Let me know what angular code you need.

```
surveybuilder.branching.rulesControllerExtender = function ($scope) {
    function setBranchTargets() {
        $scope.bTargets = $scope.branchTargets.filter(function (x) { return x.ID !== $scope.QuestionnaireItem.Id; });
    }
    setBranchTargets();
}
```

Comment: can you share your angular code as well

Comment: What it is doing https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions

Comment: What are you trying to output within the options?

Comment: The Text property of each bTarget. In another project, field names were updated (C# field names) and this seems to have broke it. I am not an Ng-dev

Comment: can you add a `console.log($scope.bTargets)` to your code and paste the output so we can see what the data looks like?

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
ng-options="t.Text for t in bTargets track by t.ID"
```